# Procedure with update new information

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, procedure

So I have been working on simple procedure for school that asks me to:

(Create a stored procedure called UpdateProduct that takes in a required Product ID parameter and optionally any other one or more fields in the Product table. Then the proc will update any fields passed in but leave any other fields as they were.

1. If executed like this: UpdateProduct @productID = 1, @name = ‘Steel Ball Bearing’; Only the name should change, all other fields should still contain the value there before the procedure
   was called)

This is what I have but still I cant seem to get it to work properly. I am going nuts because I have been trying to figure this out for several days. Any help pointing out my mistake would be awesome.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

CREATE PROC UpdateProduct2
@ProductID INT ,
@Name nvarchar (50)= ISNULL,
@ProductNumber nvarchar (25) =ISNULL,
@Color nvarchar (15)=ISNULL

AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE [Production].[Product] 
SET
Name = ISNULL (@Name,Name),
ProductNumber = ISNULL (@ProductNumber,ProductNumber),
Color = ISNULL (@Color, Color)
WHERE @Name=Name


END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your where clause should be:

```
WHERE   ProductID = @ProductID;
```

rather than

```
WHERE @Name=Name
```

Also you need to use `NULL` rather than `ISNULL` to set the parameter defaults:

```
CREATE PROC UpdateProduct2
    @ProductID int,
    @Name nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @ProductNumber nvarchar(25) = NULL,
    @Color nvarchar(15) = NULL

AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE [Production].[Product] 
    SET     Name = ISNULL (@Name,Name),
            ProductNumber = ISNULL (@ProductNumber,ProductNumber),
            Color = ISNULL (@Color, Color)
    WHERE   ProductID = @ProductID; 
END
```

---

**EDIT**

To answer the question about specifying `NULL` as the default, yes there is a reason, it allows you to call the procedure without passing the parameter.

Take the following two procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.P1 @p1 VARCHAR(20), @p2 VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT P1 = @p1, P2 = @p2;
END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.P2 @p1 VARCHAR(20) = NULL, @p2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT P1 = @p1, P2 = @p2;
END;
```

The first using no default, and the latter with NULL as the default. The only way to call the first procedure is to send all parameters, e.g.

```
EXECUTE dbo.p1;
EXECUTE dbo.p1 @P2 = 'TEST';
EXECUTE dbo.p1 @P1 = 'TEST';
```

Will generate the following errors:

```
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure P1, Line 0
Procedure or function 'P1' expects parameter '@p1', which was not supplied.
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure P1, Line 0
Procedure or function 'P1' expects parameter '@p1', which was not supplied.
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure P1, Line 0
Procedure or function 'P1' expects parameter '@p2', which was not supplied.
```

Whereas this:

```
EXECUTE dbo.p2;
EXECUTE dbo.p2 @P2 = 'TEST';
EXECUTE dbo.p2 @P1 = 'TEST';
```

Will generate:

```
P1      P2
NULL    NULL

P1      P2
NULL    TEST

P1      P2
TEST    NULL
```

Comment: Hi, why we need to set `@Name nvarchar(50) = NULL`  even without initializing  by default it will be `NULL` right. Is there any good reason behind it

Comment: Wow, I didn't even realize I never changed the WHERE clause. I was testing it with different parameters and didn't catch my mistake. And as NoDiplayName asked, is there a reason to put NULL values in the Variable setup?

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yes, it allows the procedure to be called without passing the parameter, you are telling the compiler that the parameter is optional. See the edit to my answer for a working example.

Comment: @GarethD - Thank you. I know i will get a good explanation awesome.